# Merging ShapeFiles with QGIS for UK counties

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge, united-kingdom

I want to draw a map for all the counties of the UK including Northern Ireland. Since I cannot find a source of counties including both Northern Ireland and Britain, I tried to merge two shapefiles with QGIS from different sources (Northern Ireland and Britain) by myself.

On QGIS, it looks good when I look at the map with two different layers.

[image: Map showing county boundaries of Northern Ireland and Britain]

But when I try to merge the two shapefiles, Northern Ireland overlays Britain as shown below.

[image: Map of British county boundaries]

Is there anything I can do to get my ideal result like the first image?

Comment: And what happens when you copy paste the features from shapefile 1 into 2 or the other way around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reproject one layer to another name and the CRS of the other before you can merge them.

Merging only works if both files look well-placed with `On-the-fly-reprojection`turned **OFF**.

Comment: Yeah the British ones will in EPSG:27700 British National Grid, but that does not contain NI. The NI ones will be something different. Might be best to re-project them both into ETRS89 EPSG:4258.